# ¿Cómo anular estilos css sin usar !important?

Tags: html, css

Estoy utilizando  **Vue.js** y **Ant Design of Vue**, intento sobreescribir los estilos del siguiente componente:

```
<template>
  <a-input placeholder="Basic usage" />
</template>
```

He buscado en la documentacion pero no encuentro, he logrado sobrescribir los estilos usando **!important** en css pero tengo entendido que es una mala practica

¿Hay alguna otra forma de sobrescribir los estilos del componente?

```
<style>

input {
  background: #e4e6eb !important;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
.ant-input {
    border-color: #e4e6eb !important;
    border: none !important;
}
.ant-input:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
::placeholder {
  color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considera lo siguiente:

La especificidad en CSS nos ayuda a identificar el nivel de prioridad que para el navegador le implica un selector y de esta forma le de unos u otros estilos.

En ese orden de ideas tenemos en el nivel más alto a:

- Selector de id
- Selector de clases, atributos y pseudo clases
- Selector de tipo y pseudo elementos

Por el otro lado estás teniendo que aplicar important por qué el CSS aunque es en cascada, para los inputs usas un selector de tipo el cual es el de menor peso.

Entonces para este caso, pudieras

Aplicar un selector de tipo y además agregar a este mismo selector agregar uno de atributo de está forma:

```
input[type="text"] { ...... }
```

Lo cual le dará mayor especificidad y en teoría debería anular el estilo anterior y aplicar el nuevo.

Para el caso donde tienes una clase, podemos aplicar:

Un selector de tipo y además agregarle un selector de clase lo cual lo haría más específico por encima de solo seleccionar por medio de su clase, así:

```
input.ant-input { ..... }
```

**FUENTES DE CONSULTA**

- [Calculadora de especificidad](https://specificity.keegan.st/)
- [Teoría sobre especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad)