# Problemas con media queries que no pisan los estilos y que si lo hacen con "!important"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3, sass

Estoy aprendiendo html y css acompañado del uso de bootstrap y sass, en este caso estoy pasando a responsive mi sitio web y me encuentro con la dificultad de que ciertas clases no se pisan, al principio pensé que era un error en la formulación de la mediaquerie, sin embargo, no es así, si agrego "!important" a las propiedades que deseo pisar, lo aplica.

La mediaquerie esta posicionada al final de la hoja de estilos, tanto en el archivo css creado por la compilación de las hojas scss como en la importaci{on de los parciales al scss general.

También me llama la atención que no son todas las variables, solo algunas, comparto captura del código de la vista desktop, y también del inspector señalando como la vista desktop pisa a la tablet en este caso.

Espero que me puedan dar una mano, saludos y gracias de antemano!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: [**Especificidad**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Problema encontrado, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo anular estilos css sin usar !important?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366768/c%c3%b3mo-anular-estilos-css-sin-usar-important) || Marqué como duplicado la pregunta porque técnicamente ambas preguntas se responden con la misma respuesta.

Comment: Revisar la documentación me ayudo a repasar y pensar de nuevo lo que estaba haciendo! El problema se encontraba en la aplicación de scss en las mediaqueries, las clases no se encontraban anidadas de igual forma que en la vista desktop.